# Is it necessary to reset the query after using get_posts()?

Tags: wordpress

I have placed following code for retrieving 3 posts on my homepage, and the code is working fine, now I just want to know that Is that necessary to reset the query using "wp_reset_postdata()" after using get_posts or there is no need to wp_reset_postdata() function as the following query is working fine..

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLWun.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't used `setup_postdata` (explicitly or implicitly via `$myWpQuery->the_post()`) , you won't need to reset the post data. `get_posts()` itself doesn't change the post context, so `get_the_ID()` etc will work the same before and after using `get_posts()`.

Comment: yes, I have used setup_postdata. please check screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLWun.png and let me now that I have to use wp_reset_postdata()  or not

Answer (score 0):

It is standard method to reset query. However, you can skip it; it is not necessary if you wont have any other queries to the DB for posts on the same template page.

Comment: Yes, I am using another query to fetch data from the database,  in the same template file.